# Can't find usability site about small quirks

Tags: website-design

I once visited a usability website where people submitted the small quirks that they liked about an interface. For example, one submission was about how [Apple.com](http://apple.com)'s search bar expands when you place focus on it. I can't find that site anymore. It's name could have been:

- Little Big Things
- Tiny Big Things

Anyone know the link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Close, but no cigar :) It's [littlebigdetails.com](http://littlebigdetails.com/).

Comment: Awesome site! Subscribe to their RSS feed.

Answer (score 2):

http://littlebigdetails.com/

Thanks for turning me onto a new UI website! Added to favorites.

(Also to help you tune your "google fu" I searched: "Little Big Things UI" and it was the first result.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add "UI" to my search string.

Answer (score 0):

A couple I have are:

- http://www.smileycat.com/
- http://mobile-patterns.com/

Comment: Sorry, I have a bit more, but only 2 at one time I suppose? 

 - http://patterntap.com/collections/

Thanks for http://littlebigdetails.com/ didn't have that one.

Comment: I liked UI Scraps http://uiscraps.tumblr.com/ but they have seem to have gone dormit.